# Are all CSS properties supported in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create parallax effect in React. I found a guide how to create parallax using css only. However, when I add it to React (copied html and css), it didn't do anything, the styling doesn't affect the rendering. [I am following this guide](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

HTML:

```
<div className="parallax">
  <div className="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
    Background
  </div>
  <div className="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
    Foreground
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

Is it possible that some of these properties aren't supported in React or what is the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not a matter if React supports the CSS, CSS is complete a separate entity from React. It comes down to coding error or browser support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how come that these CSS styles don't work in React app but work in static HTML? Don't React change the rendering of it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the mistake was that I wasn't offsetting the elements. Nevertheless, it's not good way of creating parallax in React, because it creates its own scrollbar inside the component where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

In JS and JSX, 'class' is a keyword. So you have to use 'className' instead of 'class'.

Here is the updated HTML code

```html
<div className="parallax">
 <div className="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
   Background
 </div>
 <div className="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
   Foreground
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. Sorry. I copied code from the tutorial and not from my app, it doesn't work with classNames as well.

Comment: Did you import the CSS file into your  (component) .js/.jsx file.                         example:  Import './parallax-styles.css';

Comment: Yes, I did that. I know fundamentals of the React.

Comment: I can't give any further solution to your problem without seeing the whole source code, but the simple answer to your main question is All the CSS properties that are working in the static HTML should work in the react application too. because CSS is a completely separate entity from reactJS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right. I just found that creating a parallax effect in React is not an easy task, because you have to deal with the inner scrollbar in components where you use it.